# JMH - why do I need Blackhole.consumeCPU()

Tags: java, benchmarking, microbenchmark, jmh, blackhole

I'm trying to understand why it is wise to use `Blackhole.consumeCPU()`?

Something I found about `Blackhole.consumeCPU()` on Google

> Sometimes when we run run a benchmark across multiple threads we also
> want to burn some cpu cycles to simulate CPU business when running our
> code. This can't be a Thread.sleep as we really want to burn cpu. The
> Blackhole.consumeCPU(long) gives us the capability to do this.

My example code:

```java
    import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

    import org.openjdk.jmh.annotations.Benchmark;
    import org.openjdk.jmh.annotations.BenchmarkMode;
    import org.openjdk.jmh.annotations.Level;
    import org.openjdk.jmh.annotations.Measurement;
    import org.openjdk.jmh.annotations.Mode;
    import org.openjdk.jmh.annotations.OutputTimeUnit;
    import org.openjdk.jmh.annotations.Scope;
    import org.openjdk.jmh.annotations.Setup;
    import org.openjdk.jmh.annotations.State;
    import org.openjdk.jmh.annotations.Warmup;
    import org.openjdk.jmh.infra.Blackhole;
    import org.openjdk.jmh.runner.Runner;
    import org.openjdk.jmh.runner.RunnerException;
    import org.openjdk.jmh.runner.options.Options;
    import org.openjdk.jmh.runner.options.OptionsBuilder;

    @State(Scope.Thread)
    @OutputTimeUnit(TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS)
    public class StringConcatAvgBenchmark {

    StringBuilder stringBuilder1;
    StringBuilder stringBuilder2;

    StringBuffer stringBuffer1;
    StringBuffer stringBuffer2;

    String string1;
    String string2;

    /*
     * re-initializing the value after every iteration
     */
    @Setup(Level.Iteration)
    public void init() {
        stringBuilder1 = new StringBuilder("foo");
        stringBuilder2 = new StringBuilder("bar");

        stringBuffer1 = new StringBuffer("foo");
        stringBuffer2 = new StringBuffer("bar");

        string1 = new String("foo");
        string2 = new String("bar");

    }

    @Benchmark
    @Warmup(iterations = 10)
    @Measurement(iterations = 100)
    @BenchmarkMode(Mode.AverageTime)
    public StringBuilder stringBuilder() {
        // operation is very thin and so consuming some CPU
        Blackhole.consumeCPU(100);
        return stringBuilder1.append(stringBuilder2);
        // to avoid dead code optimization returning the value
    }

    @Benchmark
    @Warmup(iterations = 10)
    @Measurement(iterations = 100)
    @BenchmarkMode(Mode.AverageTime)
    public StringBuffer stringBuffer() {
        Blackhole.consumeCPU(100);      
        // to avoid dead code optimization returning the value
        return stringBuffer1.append(stringBuffer2);
    }

    @Benchmark
    @Warmup(iterations = 10)
    @Measurement(iterations = 100)
    @BenchmarkMode(Mode.AverageTime)
    public String stringPlus() {
        Blackhole.consumeCPU(100);      
        return string1 + string2;
    }

    @Benchmark
    @Warmup(iterations = 10)
    @Measurement(iterations = 100)
    @BenchmarkMode(Mode.AverageTime)
    public String stringConcat() {
        Blackhole.consumeCPU(100);      
        // to avoid dead code optimization returning the value
        return string1.concat(string2);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws RunnerException {

        Options options = new OptionsBuilder()
                .include(StringConcatAvgBenchmark.class.getSimpleName())
                .threads(1).forks(1).shouldFailOnError(true).shouldDoGC(true)
                .jvmArgs("-server").build();
        new Runner(options).run();
    }
    }
```

Why are the results of this Benchmark better with the `blackhole.consumeCPU(100)` ?

---

**UPDATE:**

Output with `blackhole.consumeCPU(100)`:

```js
    Benchmark                      Mode  Cnt    Score    Error  Units
    StringBenchmark.stringBuffer   avgt   10  398,843 ± 38,666  ns/op
    StringBenchmark.stringBuilder  avgt   10  387,543 ± 40,087  ns/op
    StringBenchmark.stringConcat   avgt   10  410,256 ± 33,194  ns/op
    StringBenchmark.stringPlus     avgt   10  386,472 ± 21,704  ns/op
```

Output **without** `blackhole.consumeCPU(100)`:

```js
    Benchmark                      Mode  Cnt   Score    Error  Units
    StringBenchmark.stringBuffer   avgt   10  51,225 ± 19,254  ns/op
    StringBenchmark.stringBuilder  avgt   10  49,548 ±  4,126  ns/op
    StringBenchmark.stringConcat   avgt   10  50,373 ±  1,408  ns/op
    StringBenchmark.stringPlus     avgt   10  87,942 ±  1,701  ns/op
```

I think I know now why they used this, because the benchmarks are too quick without some delay.
With `blackhole.consumeCPU(100)` you can measure each benchmark better and receive more significant results.
Is that right ?

Comment: Define "better"? I don't see any comparison in your question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Adding artificial delay would not normally improve the benchmark.

But, there are some cases where the operation you are measuring is contending over some resources, and you need a backoff that only consumes CPU, and hopefully does nothing else. See e.g. the case in :
 http://shipilev.net/blog/2014/nanotrusting-nanotime/

The benchmark in original question is not such a case, therefore I'd speculate `Blackhole.consumeCPU` is used there without a good reason, or at least that reason is not called out specifically in the comments. Don't do that.